# AWS commands not getting executed on CRONTAB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cron, aws-cli

Before I proceed, please let me tell that I tried all methods mentioned at stackoverflow and other forums but nothing worked on my CentOS 6.8 server.

Here is what I have written in crontab

```
00 5 * * * /usr/bin/aws /var/www/html/james/crons/s3_downloader.sh
```

And s3_downloader.sh file full content is:

```
#!/bin/bash
aws s3 sync "s3://my_bucket/my_folder/" "/var/www/html/james/downloads/my_folder/";
```

But nothing is working when cron tab runs it. However everything works fine when I run it via command line screen on server.

My server has installed the AWS at path (using ROOT user): **/usr/bin/aws** (using **which aws**)

Here is the methods I have tried (but nothing worked for me):

-->Changed the path for aws in file contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/aws
aws s3 sync "s3://my_bucket/my_folder/" "/var/www/html/james/downloads/my_folder/";
```

--> Did export settings on ROOT console

```
export AWS_CONFIG_FILE="/root/.aws/config"
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXX
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=YYYY
```

**Edit**:
When I logged the response from crontab to a log

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:
```

Here is full response: http://pastebin.com/XAKQUVzT

**Edit 2**

After more debugging, I can see the error coming out (in cron log) is:

**env: /var/www/html/james/crons/s3_downloader.sh: Permission denied**

Comment: What are the permissions (`ls -ld`) on `/var/www/html/james/crons/s3_downloader.sh` and of all the containing folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
```

cd path of the folder with scripts

```
/usr/local/bin/aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids idoftheinstance
```

Include the path of aws `/usr/local/bin/aws` and good.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Your crontab entry is wrong. You have passed the name of your shell script (`/var/www/html/james/crons/s3_downloader.sh`) as a parameter to `/usr/bin/aws`.

You should either call `aws s3 sync` directly from within the crontab entry, or call your shell script (and make the shell script call `aws s3 sync`), but you're trying to do both.

So, change the crontab entry to execute the shell script (and make sure that the shell script is actually executable).

```
00 5 * * * /var/www/html/james/crons/s3_downloader.sh
```

Comment: Even I did it, the error is same in logs - http://pastebin.com/XAKQUVzT

Comment: Does your shell script start with #!/bin/bash or with #!/usr/bin/aws? Use the former.